# How to null check on Money Field in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm

I want to null check for money field in .net MVC web services
how to null check 
I write this but i don't get answer

```
//create module
public Money Amount { get; set; }

//Null Check
if ((EntityObject.Amount) != null)
{
    object Entity.Attributes.Add("budget amount", EntityObject.Amount);
}
```

How I write null check at Money field?

Comment: It should work. If you have initialized the Amount field, `Amount.Value` gives you a decimal value which is 0 by default.

Comment: When I write `Amount.Value` it gives error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Money is a special datatype, you have to handle like below using `GetAttributeValue`.

```
Money myMoneyField = (Money)EntityObject.GetAttributeValue<Money>(Amount);

decimal actualAmount;

if (myMoneyField != null)
{
    actualAmount = myMoneyField.Value;
}
else 
{ 
    actualAmount = 0; 
}

Entity.Attributes.Add("budget_amount", new Money(actualAmount));
```

Comment: Arun as always with the amazing answer.  I used this, in combination with a similar check on a preEntityImage, to ensure my code won't puke with a Null money value.  Great piece of info here, thanks again Arun!

Answer (score 2):

`Entity.GetAttributeValue<T> Method (String)` is good to avoid nulls, but please be careful that it will return `Default values` for some data types.

http://www.crmanswers.net/2015/04/getattributevalue-demystified.html
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx

if you are using Late bound `Entity` class, then you can do as below:

```
if ((EntityObject.Attributes.Contains("youMoneyFieldName")
{
   decimal moneyInDecimal = ((Money)EntityObject["youMoneyFieldName"]).Value;
   object Entity.Attributes.Add("budget amount", new Money(moneyInDecimal));
}
```

Before checking for null value, make sure you have retrieved the attribute in your Query like below:

// Retrieve the account containing several of its attributes.

```
ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(
    new String[] { "youMoneyFieldName" });

EntityObject retrievedEntity = (EntityObject)_serviceProxy.Retrieve("yourEntityName", GuidId, cols);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx